# How can I programmatically reset a user's password

Tags: 7, users

I have a native mobile application communicate with my drupal 7 site via services module.  I'd like to give users the ability to reset their password from the app.  Is there a way to initiate this process programmatically, so a an email is generated with a one time use token that expires in 24 hours?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`_user_mail_notify()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7) function, along with a user object, to invoke the password reset email:

```
// Load a user (admin in this case).
$account = user_load(1);

// Invoke the email. It will be queued along with other system mail to be sent during cron
_user_mail_notify('password_reset', $account);
```

A one time login URL with a 24 hour expiry is included by default with that particular email.

Comment: Sorry.  I haven't tested this yet.  The feature I was going to use it for was pushed back one release, so I'll be doing this sometime this month.  I imagine it'll work since it seems very straightforward.  Thanks.